# In Flutter' Stepper, how to put the title of the Step below the counter?

Tags: flutter, stepper

If use the Stepper in horizontal mode, I get the following result.

[image: Stepper in horziontal mode]

However, I want the title of the Step to appear below the counter. How can I achieve that in Flutter?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `_StepperState` class there is method `_buildHorizontal` with code:

```
Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 72.0,
            child: Center(
              child: _buildIcon(i),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
            child: _buildHeaderText(i),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

where `_buildHeaderText` returns title or title with subtitle.
So, you can't do what you want with standard `Stepper` - you have to customize this class

Comment: I am also trying to make the same. what you mean by customize this class. You mean _StepperState?. How can I customize that?

Comment: @Mahi for customising you have to copy source code to your project and change what you want

Comment: You may also use `label` parameter of `Step` class which is positioned below the circle.