# how to add Alternate labels in Flutter Stepper?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, stepper

Is there a way to add alternate labels to the stepper in flutter, as shown below.

[image]

https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/steppers.html#steppers-types-of-steppers

Comment: This question is the same as another： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835395/in-flutter-stepper-how-to-put-the-title-of-the-step-below-the-counter/68208127#68208127